# Nginx subdomain configuration not being picked up/working

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I'm trying to setup a server block for a subdomain, but nginx doesn't seem to pick up the configuration (properly). What it does is just pickup the first configuration block available and set it as the appropriate configuration.

My DNS records are as following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFGGq.jpg

My virtual host block looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name stage.remykooistra.nl www.stage.remykooistra.nl;

  root /var/www/stage.remykooistra.nl;
  index index.html index.php;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ /(cronjobs|config|lib|app/code){
    deny all;
    return 404;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include   /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

This is basically the same setup I use for almost all my server blocks, with a few exceptions such as SSL and other denied folder etc..

I hope someone could point out what I'm doing wrong here because I'm really confused on why it just doesn't pick up the right configuration.

Comment: Your description of the fault is unclear. Could you describe in more detail what appears to be going wrong? Given the server block you present, I would expect nginx to be catching both www and non-www versions of your hostname and treating them in exactly the same way.

Comment: Ofcourse, I'm sorry for being unclear. What is happening is that I'm trying to reach the subdomain "stage.remykooistra.nl", which is a 'child website'  of "remykooistra.nl" but in another directory. Though when I visit that link, I get displayed another website called "settox.com" which is another website on my server. So basically what is going wrong is that the configuration is not doing anything at all when I visit the subdomain link and it just hooks me up with another website's configuration (that appears to be the case). (added some more detail)

Comment: There are some DNS errors: http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=stage.remykooistra.nl But it is resolving to the same IP as the settox.com host so is going to your webserver. Did you restart Nginx? Are you sure this config is being loaded by Nginx?

Comment: Seconding Jay, the first thing to ascertain is whether or not your config is actually being loaded. I don't see anything wrong with your server block that would stop it from working, but that's all for naught if nginx isn't parsing it. A mistake I have made in the past is writing a config to be included but forgetting to name it correctly; `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` does not match on `example.com`, and I've spent some time tearing my hair out before realising I should've named a file `example.com.conf`...

Comment: Well the configuration was not loaded at all like you pointed out. There was a small typo in my .conf file where I typed .cofn instead .conf .. Sorry for the obvious error, I'm a bit overworked atm.. Thank you both for the quick help, as I'm sure I would've kept overlooking what I did wrong!

Comment: Quite amazing timing on those comments, eh?

Comment: Hehe yeah that was some good timing :P

Comment: Allow me to post the answer for posterity. Others may benefit from it in the future. Great teamwork nonetheless! Has happened to me plenty of times, wasting a lot of time having forgotten to reload, or the tiniest of typo's. Succes met je framework!

Comment: Aah yes that seems like a good idea. I accepted your answer! I will take a look into the DNS issues that are currently present on my domains and ofcourse add the www.stage record. Dankje :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bar some small DNS issues: http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=stage.remykooistra.nl everything seems OK so I wonder whether your Nginx conf has actually loaded. Check your filenames and restart Nginx.

Also, for www.stage. to work, you need another DNS record.